# Determine 3D position of object using polar coordinate measurements

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, polar-coordinates

Suppose I am located at fixed point $P$ in $3$-space. However, the coordinates of point $P$ are unknown.

I have a map with $N$ landmark points around me, and the world space coordinate of each landmark is known.

I establish an arbitrary local spherical coordinate system around $P$, and am able to look at each of the $N$ landmark points and determine $\phi$ and $\theta$ from $P$, Note that $\rho$, the distance from $P$ to each landmark, is unknown. I then use $\phi$ and $\theta$ to find the unit direction vector from $P$ to each landmark in local coordinates.

Is there a solution to determine

- Position $P$ in world coordinates
- Matrix $M$ to convert world coordinates to local coordinates
- Matrix $M^{-1}$ to convert local coordinates to world coordinates

and how many landmarks $N$ are needed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).